# How to set the value of array in formgroup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, 'checklists')) {
      if (Array.isArray(data.checklists)) {
        data.checklists.map((dt: any) => {
          dt.tasks.forEach((task: any) => {
            const dataArray = new FormGroup({});
            dataArray.addControl('failed', new FormControl(true, Validators.required));
            dataArray.addControl('remarks', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
            dataArray.addControl('task', new FormControl(task));
            formArray.push(dataArray);
          });
        });

        data.checklists.map((dt: any) => {
          assetArray.push(dt.asset);
        });
      }
    }
    const formField = {
      remarks: new FormControl(''),
      tasks: formArray,
      room: this.creds.credentials['room'],
      asset: assetArray
    };
    return this.fb.group(formField);
```

how to set the value from the addControl with new FormControl, cause what I'm trying to do is to create a form with `create data` and `edit data`.

I tried to change this to:

```
            dataArray.addControl('failed', new FormControl(task['failed], Validators.required));
            dataArray.addControl('remarks', new FormControl(task['remark'], Validators.required));
            dataArray.addControl('task', new FormControl(task['task']));
```

but it doesn't display the data from the form. but when it check on the console it work.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using `patchValue` to set value.

Here is a small example i wrote here.

```
const group = new FormGroup({
  control1 : new FormControl(),
  control2 : new FormControl(),
  control3 : new FormControl()
});

const array = new FormArray([this.group]);
```

Here , if u need to set value to FormGroup means ,
try to set value for FormControl in a group using patchValue()

```
this.group.patchValue({control1:'your value here'})
this.array = new FormArray(this.group)
```

The following links may help you,

https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-formgroup-example

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: can u share the code in stackblitz to see the actual code which u tried

Comment: ```dataArray.patchValue({ 'failed': task['failed']});```

Comment: Are using '[(ngModel)]' in your html. If so remove that one and use only '[formControl]'

Comment: can u share your html and ts code to analyse more on that...